# Address sanitizer doesn't find missing delete statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022, address-sanitizer

I have enabled Address Sanitizer for my project in Visual Studio and successfully tested it on the following code from [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170).

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int x[100];

int main() {
    printf("Hello!\n");
    x[100] = 5; // Boom!
    return 0;
}
```

However, the sanitizer can't find the missing delete statement in the following code:

```cpp
struct Object {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    Object* obj = new Object();
    // Boom!
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at the resulting assembly we can see that the new operator is indeed called and isn't optimized away. The following output is taken from Debug/x86 configuration but similar outputs can be obtained for configurations Debug/x64, Release/x86 and Release/x64.

```
; 6    : int main() {

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 12                 ; 0000000cH
    mov ecx, OFFSET __62A33F1D_Source@cpp
    call    @__CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode@4

; 7    :    Object* obj = new Object();

    push    8
    call    ??2@YAPAXI@Z                ; operator new
```

Can Address Sanitizer detect this type of error? If yes, how can I achieve a successful error detection?

Comment: I don't think it's intended to detect memory leaks (there are other ways to do that), and that's what you have here.  Failing to call `delete` didn't corrupt anything, so asan ain't bothered.

Comment: C++ is just too complicated, and no tool is guaranteed to find 100% of all bugs in a C++ program.

Comment: What "boom" is there? The program exits and all the memory is freed anyway.

Comment: @tadman In school, they consider this as an error.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's true. But this error is fairly simple. For sure, there exists a tool that can detect this.

Comment: Technically it's a leak, so it's good to teach that, but in practice it's nothing. It depends on what you consider a leak or not. For leak detection you probably need something like [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2022

Comment: @Eljay Yes, this is what I use.  I find it very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft address sanitizer does not detect memory leaks. See the second note on the linked [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170).

> ... Send us feedback on what you'd like to see in future releases. Your feedback helps us prioritize other sanitizers for the future, such as `/fsanitize=thread`, `/fsanitize=leak`, `/fsanitize=memory`,  ...

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I can't find it on the page. I searched for the word "leak" and nothing. Can you add a verbatim text to your answer? Is /fsanitize=leak related to this?

Comment: Don't you see they don't support the leak sanitizer? They need the leak sanitizer to support the leak detector in the the address sanitizer. The leak sanitizer would share the code with the address sanitizer and it would detect memory leaks.

Comment: The word "leak" absolutely occurs in that page, it's in a boxed section.

Comment: @Useless Yes. It appears in `/fsanitize=leak` which I stated in my comment.

Comment: You said _I searched for the word "leak" and nothing_. Did you mean to say _I searched for the word leak, found a result and didn't understand whether it was relevant_?

Comment: Anyway, yes: the leak sanitizer is the sanitizer for detecting leaks, and MS aren't choosing to focus much on the features they don't support.

Comment: @Useless Yes. I didn't know how this relates to the problem. I expected to find some form of sentence "does not support memory leak detection" on the page but I found only that note.